# Terraform - aws_route_tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, datasource

Hope someone might be able to help me please. Basically I am trying to use the data source resource for aws_route_tables and then do a lookup on that using the aws_route resource. So what I am trying to achieve here is to create a route to the transit gateway for each route table associated to a specific VPC. However, I keep getting this error:

```
Error reading config for aws_route[rt_tgw]: parse error at 1:40: expected "}" but found "["
```

This is the documentation I was following:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/route_tables

I am using Terraform version 11.15 by the way and this is the code I have got:

```
variable "environment_group" {
  description = "Name given to the resource"
  default = "test"
}

variable "create_tgw_route" {
  description = "Toggle to create the transit gateway route within the VPC route table"
  default = true
}

variable "tgw_route_cidr" {
  description = "Specify the destination cidr block for the transit gateway route within the VPC route table"
  default = "10.0.0.0/8"
}

variable "transit_gateway_id" {
  default = ""
  description = "Temporary variable that should be replaced by a data lookup in due time"
}

data "aws_vpc" "vpc_id" {
  count = "${var.create_tgw_route ? 1 : 0}"

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["vpc-${var.environment_group}"]
  }
}

data "aws_route_tables" "rtb" {
  count = "${var.create_tgw_route ? 1 : 0}"

  vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.vpc_id.id}"

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["rt-${var.environment_group}-*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_route" "rt_tgw" {
  count = "${var.create_tgw_route ? 1 : 0}"

  route_table_id            = "${tolist(data.aws_route_tables.rtb.ids)[count.index]}"
  destination_cidr_block    = "${var.tgw_route_cidr}"
  transit_gateway_id        = "${var.transit_gateway_id}"
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think that is going to work. In order to use a data source you first need to have a resource created. Unless I am missing something from your question.

Comment: the route tables are already created from a different repo

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad. Is there another piece of code missing maybe? It seems that not all is there. And posting a bit more output during the plan/apply phase would help I guess.

Comment: The codes that are just missing are the variables i.e. transit_gateway_id, tgw_route_cidr and environment_group. Which I thought does not have to be pasted in the question as its pretty much straight forward with those ones

The plan output is the error code I pasted in the question

Comment: FYI, the plan output (error) is complaining about the resource "aws_route" route_table_id value i.e.  


"${tolist(data.aws_route_tables.rtb.ids)[count.index]}"

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have managed to fix this. I changed the resource block to this:

```
resource "aws_route" "rt_tgw" {
  count = "${var.create_tgw_route ? length(data.aws_route_tables.rtb.ids) : 0}"

  route_table_id            = "${data.aws_route_tables.rtb.ids[count.index]}"
  destination_cidr_block    = "${var.tgw_route_cidr}"
  transit_gateway_id        = "${var.transit_gateway_id}"
}
```

So basically 2 things I changed.

1. Amending the count value to ensure that what ever route table is looked up in data source will be the number of routes created. In this case is 3 route tables = 3 routes created
2. Amending the 'route_table_id' value as for some reason version 11 does not like the way it is shown in the documentation.